# Is there a way to print a large 2d array in one go?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, multidimensional-array

So I'm writing a program for a kind of game that happens in the console, and I need to print a two dimensional array 20 times per second, and move each element in the way needed. So by printing the array over and over again and moving an element a little bit each time, I'm giving the illusion of movement. My problem is when I print this array in the classic way (nested loops) it takes time and that causes my game to become somewhat laggy, and the elements seem to keep blinking since the screen gets cleared each time and the array gets printed again. I'm aware that I could make this game in a more effective manner using the ncurses library, but that's not what I'm doing now.

I tried using something called WriteConsoleOutputCharacter from the windows.h library, but I couldn't get it to work. in would print the console one time, stop, then end the program unexpectedly. I can't figure out what I'd done wrong there, but I'm a newbie anyways and I don't know how that function works. If WriteConsoleOutputCharacter is the solution, I'd love if you'd expand a little on it and walk me through. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could do the "painting" in a 2d array and then print that to screen with one call: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/PvKWhMxqz). I doubt it'll be very fast though. Windows Console output isn't very fast.

Comment: Console emulators are simply not fast enough to do a complete refresh 20 times a second. Optimize what you redraw.

Comment: In your question, you wrote: `"and the elements seem to keep blinking since the screen gets cleared each time and the array gets printed again"` - Why are you clearing the screen? Can't you simply overwrite the old content with the new content? This will probably eliminate or at least significantly reduce the flickering.

Answer (score 2):

If you must clear the screen before drawing every frame, then I recommend that you use double buffering to prevent the console from flickering.

You can use the function [`CreateConsoleScreenBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/createconsolescreenbuffer) to create an additional buffer for your console.

You can then write to the inactive buffer. Once the inactive buffer is ready to be displayed, you can switch buffers with the function [`SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleactivescreenbuffer).

You will probably want to set both console buffers to the same size beforehand, using the function [`SetConsoleScreenBufferSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolescreenbuffersize).

See [this overview of Console Screen Buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers) from the Microsoft documentation for further information.

Comment: The issue isn't flicker. The issue is running game physics at a predictable refresh rate. This answer does nothing to address the core issue.

Comment: @IInspectable: OP mentioned "blinking" in the question, which probably means "flickering". I believe that this is the primary issue. Any performance issues will probably no longer be relevant, once double buffering is implemented.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to solve the issue of the same array taking time to print, and that's more important than the actual time difference between the printing of *different* arrays, then I would suggest making a string with the value of the entire array, just like you want it printed, and then just printing the string.

If this solution doesn't work for you then try editing your question and add the actual code you're using so you can get suggestions on how to optimize it and make it more efficient if possible so your game won't lag as much.

Furthermore, this might not solve your problem exactly but I would suggest switching to WPF as it is a much easier platform to create such a game, way better than a console.

hopefully, I helped(;